# Installing navidrome throws "Unit navidrome.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error."

Tags: installation

While installing navidrome I am getting this error:

```
hardik:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl start navidrome.service

Failed to start navidrome.service: Unit navidrome.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See system logs and 'systemctl status navidrome.service' for details.
```

The content of navidrome.service is given below:-

**navidrome.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Navidrome Music Server and Streamer compatible with Subsonic/Airsonic
After=remote-fs.target network.target
AssertPathExists=/var/lib/navidrome

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=<user>
Group=<group>
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/navidrome/navidrome --configfile "/var/lib/navidrome/navidrome.toml"
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/navidrome
TimeoutStopSec=20
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

# See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html
DevicePolicy=closed
NoNewPrivileges=yes
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateUsers=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_INET AF_INET6
RestrictNamespaces=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
SystemCallFilter=~@clock @debug @module @mount @obsolete @reboot @setuid @swap
ReadWritePaths=/var/lib/navidrome

# You can uncomment the following line if you're not using the jukebox This
# will prevent navidrome from accessing any real (physical) devices
#PrivateDevices=yes

# You can change the following line to `strict` instead of `full` if you don't
# want navidrome to be able to write anything on your filesystem outside of
# /var/lib/navidrome.
ProtectSystem=full

# You can uncomment the following line if you don't have any media in /home/*.
# This will prevent navidrome from ever reading/writing anything there.
#ProtectHome=true

# You can customize some Navidrome config options by setting environment variables here. Ex:
#Environment=ND_BASEURL="/navidrome"
```

Why am I getting the error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I was trying to start the service on my raspberry pi 3 using **navidrome_0.47.5_Linux_arm64.tar.gz**. When I replaced it with files from **navidrome_0.47.5_Linux_armv7.tar.gz**, everything went fine. It's likely that you might be trying to run the executable with a wrong architecture.

Also I believe that User and Group should contain the actual user and group that you chose here:

```
sudo install -d -o <user> -g <group> /opt/navidrome
sudo install -d -o <user> -g <group> /var/lib/navidrome
```